# What is a "temporary mental apparition"?

Tags: meaning

From *The Ransom of Red Chief* by *O. Henry*:

> It was, as Bill afterward expressed it, "during a moment of **temporary mental apparition**;" but we didn't find that out till later.

What is meant by it?

Comment: Have you looked up the constituent words?

Comment: @simchona An apparition is a spirit. Or, it can be a condition in which a object can be in two places at once. The Harry Potter definition is 'teleport/disappear', but I'm not entirely sure if that's it or I'm missing something.

Comment: Sorry, asking if the OP has looked up a word is usually my first question. Why don't you come into chat and I can try to help you work through it if you'd like?

Comment: Also @muntoo: If you're asking for a literary analysis, we can't do that, but if you're just asking what a "temporary mental apparition" is we can.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a mistranscription (or malapropistic error) for ***aberration***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For context, the full first [paragraph](http://www.online-literature.com/o_henry/1041/) is:

> It looked like a good thing: but wait till I tell you. We were down South, in Alabama -- Bill Driscoll and myself -- when this kidnapping idea struck us. It was, as Bill afterward expressed it, "during a moment of temporary mental apparition"; but we didn't find that out till later.

According to [this copy of the story](http://www.pomounties.org/5683581214016/lib/5683581214016/The_Ransom_of_Red_Chief.pdf), here Bill mistakenly uses *apparition* for *aberration*--a disorder of the mind. There are several definitions of [*aberration*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aberration), but the relevant one is:

> mental irregularity or disorder, especially of a minor or temporary nature; lapse from a sound mental state.

So the *temporary mental apparition* was supposed to be *temporary mental aberration*--that is, a moment of temporary insanity.

Comment: @Muntoo: You might be interested in reading the paper I linked--there are quite a few words which are purposeful misspellings in the story.

Comment: For instance, is there really such a thing as a flannel-cake (mentioned in the second paragraph)?

Comment: @Peter: It would taste a bit fuzzy, I suppose.

Comment: @simchona Ah, lol, I was wondering about why it sounded so random and different from what one would have expected it to say. :) Maybe there's a little joke in that Bill went 'insane' and said the wrong word?

Comment: @muntoo: I've never analyzed this story, but I think the author may be saying that Bill (and Sam, who also makes mistakes) are quite the sharpest tools in the shed. If you'd like to perhaps ask *why* the author did this, then I suggest you go to Literature.SE

Comment: I asked [here](http://literature.stackexchange.com/q/756/205). (Of course, none of this stuff was assigned by my teacher! :))

Comment: @muntoo--I hope you get good answers! It'll be great for a paper, perhaps

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. Googling shows that *flannel cake* is an Irish-origin expression for something like a pancake.

Comment: @PeterShor Hold on a sec, I recognize you now - Shor's Algorithm! Your rep on `English.SE > Physics.SE > Math.SE`. Interesting. :)

Answer (score 2):

First, my copy of the story is expressed differently. My story's first paragraph:

> It looked like a good thing, but wait till I tell you. We were down south in Alabama - Bil Driscoll and myself - when we thought of this kidnapping idea. 
>   **It was "during an instant of momentary madness,"** as Bill said afterward. But we did not find that out till later.

Basically, what Bill is saying that it was a mistake. Much like later told in the story.

Comment: @sim I am rolling your edit back. I want to make the sentence more noticable.

Comment: Please don't. It makes it entirely over-formatted.

Comment: @sim It makes it clear which is the answer.